# Multiple root nodes in Alpine.js

Tags: alpine.js, root-node

Building a data table with the latest Alpine.js (v3.7.0).
Ran into a problem when trying to implement child rows (i.e an additional togglable row under the main/parent row).

Simplified version:

```html
<tbody>
<template x-for="row in currentPageData" :key="row.id">
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            Some additional content
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
</tbody>
```

While I'm not getting any errors in the console, the second node (tr) is not rendered. I assume that's because Alpine requires a single root element. Is there any way around it, as wrapping with `div` is invalid HTML and a `tbody` wrapper breaks the layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Alpine templates being rendered server-side I ended up with the following workaround:

When table has child rows I remove the root `tbody` and wrap each `tr` pair with a `tbody` of its own.

EDIT (23-9-22):

As per @NoobnSad's request code in `twig`:

```html
{% if not options.enableChildRows %}
<tbody>
{% endif %}
<template x-for="row in currentPageData" :key="row.id">
    {% if options.enableChildRows %}
    <tbody>
    {% endif %}
<tr>
    {% if options.enableChildRows %}
        {% include datatable.componentPath('childRowToggler') %}
    {% endif %}
    {% include datatable.componentPath('tableCells') %}
</tr>
{% if options.enableChildRows %}
{% include datatable.componentPath('childRow') with {tableHandle:datatable.handle} %}
</tbody>
{% endif %}
</template>
<template x-if="recordsCount===0">
{% include datatable.componentPath('notFound') %}
</template>
{% if not options.enableChildRows %}
</tbody>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: can you provide the fullcode?

Answer (score 2):

Since multiple `tbody` tags are allowed inside one table you can wrap your multiple `tr` tags in one `tbody` tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <template x-for="i in [1,2,3]" :key="i">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Test2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</table>
```

Comment: as mentioned in the question the tbody wrapper breaks the layout